# Did a talent show judge a girl based on her belief in God?

Tags: video

A video on Facebook went viral called "[Talent show Judges ask 16-year-old girl if she believes in God](https://www.facebook.com/GodorNoGod/videos/10153631363863104/)" that has subtitles claiming that a whole judge panel evaluated a girl based on her belief in God:

[image]

At the end of the video, they gave her a "No" because she doesn't believe in God. I found it ridiculous, far from being true, but looking at the comments it seems people believe that the video is true and not even a single comment casts doubt on the validity of the subtitles.

In other words, my question is: Do subtitles fit the content of the video?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the proof here... There are lots of Spanish people commenting, who obviously have no doubt in the correctness of the translation. It has also been referenced by many news sources and atheist organizations. I'm not sure how else would one prove that the translation is correct...

Comment: A TV reality show that does something outrageous and judges on something other than talent? And this is news?

Comment: What is the reason to be skeptical of this claim?

Comment: @gerrit while there are many clear cases of prejudice against atheists, it is always good to be skeptical of a claim of such prejudice. Atheists aren't immune from manufacturing a situation to support their cause (albeit I think they are less likely to do so).

Comment: Wow. Attacking a 16yo girl on a TV singing contest because she doesn't believe in God… That's amazing. I'm starting to believe in it right now.

Comment: -1, this question is trivial

Answer (score 6):

As commenters noted, several spanish people commented on the clip, none claimed that the translation was false.

The [original buzzfeed article](http://www.buzzfeed.com/bblanco/esta-chica-recibio-tremendo-sermon-en-la-tele-por-no-creer-e#.bce0Dzp2Q) was in spanish.

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=no&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzfeed.com%2Fbblanco%2Festa-chica-recibio-tremendo-sermon-en-la-tele-por-no-creer-e%23.bce0Dzp2Q&edit-text=&act=url) of the above seems to agree with the translation.

That said, even the English translation doesn't show the judges evaluating the girl based on her (lack of) faith.  The statements that comes closes are more in the vein of "You are not a good enough singer today, and as long as you don't believe in god you will never be good enough."

Comment: My spanish is not so good, but the english translation seems correct to me.

Comment: @Einenlum You almost certainly know more spanish than me.  But my answer is deliberatly based on facts that you can verify with no knowledge of spanish.

Comment: The fact that they even *knew* she didn't believe in god creates a reasonable suspicion that their perception of her singing was tainted by their bias.